# Lotus notes validation for role

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I am very new to lotus notes development.
Problem is:

In front page i have created one hyperlink as register.

```
href=""><u><font size="5" color="#0000FF" face="Arial">Register</font></u></a>
```

when i click this hyperlink it will go to this below url in hotspot.

```
@URLOpen("/htj.nsf/open")
```

Now i have two url's one is `"/homr.nsf/close"` and another is  `"/htj.nsf/open"` and we have 2 different roles Admin and normal user .... the task is now that if the role of the particular user is admin then url has to go to

```
@URLOpen("/htj.nsf/open")
```

And if it is normal user then the url has to go to  `@URLOpen("/homr.nsf/close")`
 i wrote the code in the same hotspot

```
if(role == "admin")
{
@URLOpen("/htj.nsf/open")
}else
{
@URLOpen("/homr.nsf/close")
}
```

but it is not leaving me to save as code is different so kindly please help me how can i make the role validation and open the url.

thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula to

```
@URLOpen(@If(@UserRoles = "[admin]"; "/htj.nsf/open"; "/homr.nsf/close"))
```

Comment: thanks bro. it is working when i add it in Forms but if i add in pages it is not working it is automatically taking the true statement `/htj.nsf/open` for the normal user as well. i tested it in forms it is working correctly. i have small doubt whether it works in pages or not

Comment: Add a computed text `@UserName + ": " + @Implode(@UserRoles; ", ")` to your page to see which user and which roles are active.

Comment: Approver and Rejector .... But in pages it is not working ...in forms it is working

Comment: Explain what you mean by "not working".  When you add the computed text element to a page and give it the formula that Knut specified, what do you see?

Comment: #Ricard what knut has given is absolutely correct but.... i have one more doubt which i will add it as second question